# ¿Retornar datos y leerlos desde el main en Java?

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un ejercicio el cual consta de ingresar datos de un estudiante y hacer calculos de la definitiva, pero me esta surgiendo un inconveniente a la hora de ingresar los datos ya que me los esta ejecutando dos veces y no encuentro la manera de poder ejecutarlo solo una vez.

He intentado llamar los metodos desde el main, pero tengo que pasarles parametros y es hay donde estoy un poco quedado:

**Main:**

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Principal {

   public static void main(String[] args) {   
     ArrayList<Float> nota; 
     float notaFinal = 0;
     Metodo M = new Metodo();    
     M.ingresarEstudiante();
     nota=M.ingresarNota();
     notaFinal=M.calcularNota(nota);

     System.out.print(M.imprimirDatos(notaFinal));
}
```

}

**Clase de Metodos:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Metodo {

private ArrayList<Estudiante> estudiante;

public Metodo(){
    estudiante = new ArrayList<Estudiante> ();
}

public void ingresarEstudiante(){
    int sw = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Desea ingresar un Estudiante "));
    do{
        estudiante.add(new Estudiante(
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el numero de la cédula"),
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese los nombres"),
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la edad"),
                ingresarNota()
        ));
                
        sw = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Desea ingresar otro Estudiante"));
    }while(sw == 1);
    
}

public ArrayList<Float> ingresarNota() {
    ArrayList<Float> notas = new ArrayList<Float>();        
    for (int i=1; i <=5; i++){
        notas.add(Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota" + i)));
    }            
    return notas ;       
}
    

public static float calcularNota(ArrayList<Float> notas){
   float media = 0; 
   float notaFinal = 0;
    for (float d : notas) {
      media = media + d;    
    }
    
    notaFinal = media / notas.size();
    
    return notaFinal;       
}
       
 public String imprimirDatos(float notaFinal){        
    String texto = "";
    if (notaFinal > 3.8){            
                  
        for (Estudiante estudiante : estudiante) {         
        texto += estudiante.getCedula() + " " + estudiante.getNombre()
                 + " " + estudiante.getEdad() + ", las notas son: " 
                 + estudiante.getNotas().toString() + "\n";
       }
    }else{
     texto += "No hay estudiantes con promedio mayor a 3.8";
    }
    return texto;
 }
```

}

Cualquier sugerencia y aporte es bienvenido ,

Gracias

Comment: Estás llamando a `ingresarNota()` dos veces: desde el `main` y también desde dentro del método `ingresarEstudiante()` de la clase `Metodo`. Debes decidir entonces desde dónde quieres llamar a `ingresarNota()` y quitar una de las dos llamadas.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, quiero dejar solo el ingresar notas que se llama en el método Ingresar estudiantes, el dettale es que no logro encontrar la forma de obtener esas dotas en el método main sin tener que llamar nuevamente a ingresar nota().

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto a tu clase Metodo, veo que debe requerir los datos del estudiante ùnicamente con la opciòn `1`,  te sugiero usar un while para validar ùnicamente agregar un Estudiante si el valor es `1` de otra forma termina tu aplicaciòn.

Tambièn crea una variable para exponer el valor de notas.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Metodo {

private ArrayList<Estudiante> estudiante;
ArrayList<Float> notas ; 

public Metodo(){
    estudiante = new ArrayList<Estudiante> ();
}

public void ingresarEstudiante(){
    
    int sw = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Desea ingresar un Estudiante "));
    
    while(sw == 1){
             
        estudiante.add(new Estudiante(
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el numero de la cédula"),
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese los nombres"),
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la edad"),
                ingresarNota()
        ));
      
        sw = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Desea ingresar otro Estudiante"));
        
    };

}

public ArrayList<Float> ingresarNota() {
    //ArrayList<Float> notas = new ArrayList<Float>();        
    notas = new ArrayList<Float>();        
    for (int i=1; i <=5; i++){
        notas.add(Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota" + i)));
    }            
    return notas ;       
}
    

public static float calcularNota(ArrayList<Float> notas){
   float media = 0; 
   float notaFinal = 0;
    for (float d : notas) {
      media = media + d;    
    }
    
    notaFinal = media / notas.size();
    
    return notaFinal;       
}
       
 public String imprimirDatos(float notaFinal){        
    String texto = "";
    if (notaFinal > 3.8){            
                  
        for (Estudiante estudiante : estudiante) {         
        texto += estudiante.getCedula() + " " + estudiante.getNombre()
                 + " " + estudiante.getEdad() + ", las notas son: " 
                 + estudiante.getNotas().toString() + "\n";
       }
    }else{
     texto += "No hay estudiantes con promedio mayor a 3.8";
    }
    return texto;
 }
}
```

Al exponer el valor de notas no necesitas llamar el mètodo `ingresarNota()` ya que es el principal problema del "doble llamado", solo realiza lo siguiente:

```
 ArrayList<Float> nota; 
 float notaFinal = 0;
 Metodo M = new Metodo();    
 M.ingresarEstudiante();
 //nota=M.ingresarNota();
 notaFinal=M.calcularNota(M.notas);

 System.out.print(M.imprimirDatos(notaFinal));
```